# How to parse a .zip file in Javascript before uploading to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, file-upload

I have a situation where a user may have to upload multiple text files, which are then saved on the file system. Instead of asking the user to repeat the same act multiple times I want to give them an option to upload a zip file where files are saved in a particular format.

There are 2 ways to do it.

1. Ask them to upload a zip file. Unzip the file at the server and save the independent files. If I do the whole thing in memory there is a risk of using up too much memory, so the logical thing would be to save the zip file on filesystem. But since we are deployed on Amazon, it will involve saving on S3 which further increase the latency from EC2 to S3 and I don't want the headache of tracking the Zip file as well.
2. Other option is to unzip the file on the client side itself and then individually upload the files, this way I don't need to keep track of the zip file. But i am unable to understand how can I unzip a file on the client side and iterate through multiple files/folders in it.

If there is any easier/less messier way of doing it with the first approach, I am open to that as well. The backend is in Django.

Would sincerely appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply let them select multiple files at once? [I found this example online](http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload).
Also you can combine it with drag & drop. I think dragging the multiple files into the form, will be even more comfortable than uploading a ZIP file. [Check this article to read more about the JavaScript file API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File).

Comment: This is becuase the uploaded files have particular dependencies. If there are 2x files then x are of one type and other x are of other type. And there is one to one correspondence between files in the two categories.

Comment: I think it's possible to validate these dependencies using JavaScript or a Python script on the backend. Could you please tell me a little bit more about it? Why is this validation required? Using the JavaScript file API, you can check local file types, length in bytes, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File